# How to send an HTTP request via chunked transfer encoding with Spring

Tags: java, spring, http, rest

Before I give up in frustration and rewrite this "old school style" (without the use of Spring), I am hoping that someone knowledgeable in Spring's HTTP client stuff can help me.

I have some large-ish data that I want to send via HTTP to a Web service. I'd like to be able to send it in chunks. The Spring source code makes clear that if you call `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory`'s `setBufferRequestBody` method, setting its boolean argument to `false`, the resulting `ClientHttpRequest` will "stream" to its target, i.e., it'll use "chunked transfer encoding." However, there is a caveat: use of chunked encoding will occur only if the request content length is *unknown*.

And that's my problem. I cannot, to put it awkwardly, figure out how to make content length unknown. A scenario here might be a large byte array that I'd like to send in smaller chunks rather than all at once. But it seems to me that the several pertinent `RestTemplate` calls, e.g., `exchange()` and `postForObject()`, know exactly what the request content is and how long it is. So, in a sequence like this:

```
HttpEntity<Object> entity = new HttpEntity<Object>(payload, headers);
ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = null; 
response = restTemplate.exchange(svcUrl, httpMethod, entity, byte[].class);
```

the exchange logic can inspect the `HttpEntity` to figure out the length of the request body (*payload*, in my example code). Consequently, the request is sent with a `Content-Length` header.

I feel like I must be missing something very obvious. I am grateful for any light you can shed on this.

Environment:

1. version 3.2.3 of the several Spring components
2. JDK 1.7.0_40
3. Windows 2008R2 (for now)

Comment: wrap it in a ByteArrayInputStream?

Comment: As mentioned set it to a byte array or just set the http header value your self to be -1.

Comment: I am pretty late to the party, but anyway... You say that there is a large byte array that you want to send to a web service. That byte array is, presumably, the `payload` object in the `HttpEntity` constructor, which gets sent in the request. The web service **receives** the request but does it also **send** a byte array in its response? I am asking because you set the type parameter for `ResponseEntity` also as `byte[]`. Is that correct or is that a mix-up of request and response?